# How to enable change tracking on a database without explicitly using its name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, change-tracking

I'm currently having this script that enables change tracking on one table:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.change_tracking_tables WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('TB_Styles')) = 0
Begin
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TB_Styles] ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING  WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON)
End
```

It was working on different databases till one database executed with an error stating that change tracking must be enabled on the database first, I wasn't aware of that condition (it's my first deal with change tracking in SQL), 
so I added this script before the previous script:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.change_tracking_databases WHERE database_id=DB_ID('TailorsDb')) = 0
Begin
ALTER DATABASE TailorsDb
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON  
(CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON)  
End
```

it's working, but the problem is that I'm explicitly using the database name (in `IF` and `ALTER` statements), which is not good because these scripts are run on different machines and the database name is not guaranteed to be the same.

(*I'm using `IF` statement to avoid errors when script is run more than one time accidentally)

Comment: As M. Ali suggests: When checking for the existence of one or more rows it is more efficient to use [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) rather than getting an exact [`COUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) and then just checking if it is greater than zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your code to use system function `B_NAME()` instead of hardcoding the database name.

```
Declare @DBNAME SYSNAME = DB_NAME()
      , @Sql    NVARCHAR(MAX);

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.change_tracking_databases WHERE database_id=DB_ID(@DBNAME)) = 0
Begin
    SET @Sql = N'   ALTER DATABASE '+  QUOTENAME(@DBNAME) + N'
                    SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON  
                    (CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON) '

    Exec sp_executesql  @Sql
End


IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.change_tracking_tables WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('TB_Styles')) = 0
Begin
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TB_Styles] ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING  WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON)
En
```

Also instead of using count(*) = 0 I would use something like Exists operator, it is much cleaner.

```
Declare @DBNAME SYSNAME = DB_NAME()
      , @Sql    NVARCHAR(MAX);


IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM sys.change_tracking_databases 
               WHERE database_id = DB_ID(@DBNAME))
Begin
    SET @Sql = N'   ALTER DATABASE '+  QUOTENAME(@DBNAME) + N'
                    SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON  
                    (CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON) '

    Exec sp_executesql  @Sql
End


IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                FROM sys.change_tracking_tables 
                WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('TB_Styles'))
Begin
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TB_Styles] 
        ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING  WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON)
End
```